# Could not convert ‘{40, Game.game::quit()}’ from ‘’ to ‘button’

Tags: button, arraylist, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть код:

```
button MainMenuButtons[3]{{100, 400, 400, 40, Game.quit()}, {100, 500, 400, 40, Game.quit()}, {100, 600, 400, 40, Game.quit()}};
```

При компиляции выдает:

```
error: could not convert ‘{100, 400, 400, 40, Game.game::quit()}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘button’
```

Что не так?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А ты написал конструктор для обработки списка инициализации?

Примерно что-то типа этого:

```
button (std::initializer_list<uint8> c) {
  std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), m_field);
}
```

Тут магии никакой нет, это просто обычный список, который надо обойти.

Да, кстати, а почему у тебя этот класс именуется с маленькой буквы? Лучше назвать его **Button**.

Comment: Вот мой конструктор:

    button::button(int nx, int ny, int nw, int nh, std::function<void ()>*nc())

Comment: И что дальше?

Я точно не знаю, не на чем проверить, но вот, попробуй создать дефолтный (гуглить по ключевому слову default) конструктор и/или написать свой конструктор со списком инициализации. В этом магии никакой нет и за тебя это делать никто не будет по множеству причин.

Вот тут примерно твой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor